# SlickGrid custom filter is iteration thru already filtered result set

Tags: javascript, performance, datagrid, slickgrid

The implemented custom filter works well, but I am facing a performance issue with SlickGrid js. After the custom filter is applied and an new entire to the grid is added, the filter is again applied on the entire (already) filtered result set. In my opinion the filter should only be applied on that added item.

I had a look to the documentation, but I couldn't find any hint how this behavior could be controlled.

Does anyone has any idea or was facing the same issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are using DataView, so the filter algorithm is essentially:

```
  var idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0, ii = items.length; i < ii; i++) {
    if (filter(items[i], filterArgs, dataView, i)) {
      filteredItems[idx++] = items[i];
    }
  }
```

The `filteredItems` var is local to DataView, so you'd need to either modify DataView and expose it with a getter, and then:

```
    if (filter(items[newItemIndex], filterArgs, dataView, newItemIndex)) {
      filteredItems[filteredItems.length] = items[newItemIndex];
    }
```

or you could add a new method to DataView specifically for this use case.

*Or* you could add a second parameter to the `addItem` method, say `addToFilter`, to do this function before the `refresh()` that occurs there.